# Не могу скомпилировать проект WebView2

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, webview, com

Я использую Visual Studio 2015, версия 14.0.23107.0. Версия целевой платформы проекта 10.0.17763.0.

Я прочитал [эту](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/win32) статью, и выполнил первые шаги. Я скачал решение webview2 с [GitHub‘а](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/master/GettingStartedGuides/Win32_GettingStarted) и открыл его в Visual Studio. Затем, через NuGet я успешно добавил Windows Implementation Library package (версия 1.0.200902.2), и WebView2 package (версия 0.9.579).

Затем, в `HelloWebView.cpp` я добавил

```
#include "WebView2.h"
```

Не могу скомпилировать. Ошибок в `HelloWebView.cpp` и в `WebView2.h` нет. Похоже, проблема в Windows Implementation Library.

Вот список ошибок компилятора:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(972): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед идентификатором "pszDest"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(978): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(978): error C2447: {: отсутствует заголовок функции (возможно, используется формальный список старого типа)
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1098): error C2065: STRSAFE_LPWSTR: необъявленный идентификатор
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1098): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед идентификатором "pszDest"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1104): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1104): error C2447: {: отсутствует заголовок функции (возможно, используется формальный список старого типа)
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1342): error C2065: STRSAFE_LPSTR: необъявленный идентификатор
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1342): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед идентификатором "pszDest"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1348): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1348): error C2447: {: отсутствует заголовок функции (возможно, используется формальный список старого типа)
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1473): error C2065: STRSAFE_LPWSTR: необъявленный идентификатор
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1473): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед идентификатором "pszDest"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1479): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1479): error C2447: {: отсутствует заголовок функции (возможно, используется формальный список старого типа)
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1695): error C2065: STRSAFE_LPSTR: необъявленный идентификатор
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1695): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед идентификатором "pszDest"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1699): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1699): error C2447: {: отсутствует заголовок функции (возможно, используется формальный список старого типа)
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1737): error C2065: STRSAFE_LPWSTR: необъявленный идентификатор
 1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1737): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед идентификатором "pszDest"
 1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1741): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1741): error C2447: {: отсутствует заголовок функции (возможно, используется формальный список старого типа)
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1873): error C2065: STRSAFE_LPSTR: необъявленный идентификатор
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1873): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед идентификатором "pszDest"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(1877): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"
    1>c:\users\okuma\desktop\win32_gettingstarted\packages\microsoft.windows.implementationlibrary.1.0.200902.2\include\wil\wistd_type_traits.h(3693): error C2325: _Tp: непредвиденный тип справа от ".~": требуется "add_lvalue_reference<_Tp>::type"
1>  c:\users\okuma\desktop\win32_gettingstarted\packages\microsoft.windows.implementationlibrary.1.0.200902.2\include\wil\wistd_type_traits.h(3695): note: см. ссылку на создание экземпляров класса шаблон при компиляции "wistd::__libcpp_is_nothrow_destructible<true,_Tp>"
1>c:\users\okuma\desktop\win32_gettingstarted\packages\microsoft.windows.implementationlibrary.1.0.200902.2\include\wil\common.h(587): error C2039: enable_if_t: не является членом "wistd"
1>  c:\users\okuma\desktop\win32_gettingstarted\packages\microsoft.windows.implementationlibrary.1.0.200902.2\include\wil\wistd_type_traits.h(46): note:  см. объявление "wistd"
1>c:\users\okuma\desktop\win32_gettingstarted\packages\microsoft.windows.implementationlibrary.1.0.200902.2\include\wil\common.h(587): error C2061: синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "enable_if_t"
1>c:\users\okuma\desktop\win32_gettingstarted\packages\microsoft.windows.implementationlibrary.1.0.200902.2\include\wil\common.h(587): error C2988: неопознанное объявление или определение шаблона
1>c:\users\okuma\desktop\win32_gettingstarted\packages\microsoft.windows.implementationlibrary.1.0.200902.2\include\wil\common.h(587): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: ,
1>c:\users\okuma\desktop\win32_gettingstarted\packages\microsoft.windows.implementationlibrary.1.0.200902.2\include\wil\common.h(773): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "}"
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(175): error C2065: STRSAFE_PCNZCH: необъявленный идентификатор
1>C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\strsafe.h(175): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед идентификатором "psz"
```

Comment: Не хватает какой-то библиотеки, либо не подходит ваша среда. Либо менять среду, либо с помощью #define или автозамены править файлы. Явно не хватает обьявления  `STRSAFE_LPWSTR`

Comment: [std::enable_if_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) появился в C++11. Убедитесь что в настройках проекта выставлен стандарт C++11 или новее

Comment: вернее `using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B,T>::type;// since C++14`

Comment: @MaximTimakov как раз насчёт С++14 не уверен. А можно установить поддержку более нового стандарта в уже установленную Visual Studio?

Comment: Решение там под VS2017

Comment: @user7860670 Пункт из статьи: *“ Visual Studio 2015 or later with C++ support installed.”*

Comment: может быть, но решение в репозитории под VS2017

Comment: @user7860670 как Вы это поняли?

Comment: @Artur, поддержка стандартов добавляется с обновлениями компилятора/IDE. VS2015 уже не будет их получать. То есть остается только полностью обновлять студию.

Comment: там везде версия 15 прописана  - это VS2017 https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/master/GettingStartedGuides/Win32_GettingStarted/WebView2GettingStarted.vcxproj#L2

Comment: @MaximTimakov, погуглил, вроде в VS15 C++14 реализован

Comment: @user7860670, блин поменял старый тип шаблона Com указателей на CComPtr, всё скомпилировалось, но теперь `LINK1158: не удаётся запустить rc.exe`

Comment: @user7860670 хух всё, теперь скомпилировалось и заработало. Ответ отсюда помог https://stackoverflow.com/a/14373113/12450770

Comment: @Artur добавьте ответ на собственный вопрос ниже, если не сложно

Comment: @dIm0n, да, да, конечно добавлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Заменить Windows Implementation Library на ATL:

---

```
#include <wrl.h>

#include <wil/com.h>
```

Заменить на

```
#include <atlbase.h>
```

---

```
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Controller> webviewController;

// Pointer to WebView window
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2> webviewWindow;
```

Заменить на

```
static CComPtr<ICoreWebView2Controller> webviewController;

// Pointer to WebView window
static CComPtr <ICoreWebView2> webviewWindow;
```

---

2. Если после удачной компиляции будет ошибка компоновщика `LINK1158: can’t run rc.exe`, проделать действия из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14373113/12450770).